# Why is this Sproc Scanning Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This system was built years ago in SQL7 and currently runs in SQL2k5

We have a table tProducts with a proudctid Guid as the PK/Clustered Index.  I realize for optimum performance we should modify the table but that's not a possibility at this point.  I'm joining it to the tProductSpecial table which also has a PK/Clustered Index of productid, which is also the FK in this relationship.  We have about 50k records in the tProducts table and about 35k records in the tProductSpecial table (some products have     special information and some do not).  There is one more piece.  I am using a Temporary table in the sproc to grab the logged in users security roles and loading them, this also joins to the tProducts table, roleid is non-clustered index in tProducts.  I've included some of the WHERE conditions that access these table.

```
SELECT *
FROM tProducts
  JOIN tProductSpecial ON tProducts.productid=tProductSpecial.productid
  JOIN #tRoles ON tProducts.roleid=#tRoles.roleid
WHERE
  (tProducts.productSKU = @sku AND tProducts.productStatus=1)  --DIRECT MATCH
  OR
  (  -- KEYWORD SEARCH
    CONTAINS(tProducts.*,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,''' + @lookuptext + ''')') 
    AND
    (
      @productStatus IS NULL
      OR
      (
        @productStatus IS NOT NULL
        AND
        tProducts.productStatus = @productStatus
      )          
    )
    AND 
    (  --- item on sale
      @bOnSale IS NULL
      OR @bOnSale=0
      OR
      (
        @bOnSale = 1
        AND tProducts.productOnSale=1
      )
    )
    AND
    (  -- from price
      @from=0 
      OR @from IS NULL
      OR 
      (
        @from<>0
        AND             
        tProducts.customerCost>=@from
      )         
    )
    AND
    (  --to price
      @to=0 
      OR @to IS NULL
      OR 
      (
        @to<>0
        AND             
        tProducts.customerCost<=@from
      )         
    )
    AND
    (  --how old is product
      @age IS NULL 
      OR @age = 0       
      OR
      (
        @age IS NOT NULL
        AND @age > 0
        AND DATEDIFF(day,tProducts.productCreated,GETDATE()) 
          <=CONVERT(varchar(10),@age)       
       )
     )

  ORDER BY tProducts.productSKU
```

Comment: Is this a better fit for http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried a "divide and conquer" approach to this query?  Your WHERE clause is pretty big.  Any one of these conditions could cause a table scan if each is not part of an index.  My first guess would be that CONTAINS() clause, but I would confirm by commenting out the stuff that I didn't suspect and see if the execution plan got better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably due to parameter sniffing - you're using the same plan over and over again even if the parameters are different and only sometimes a scan would be the best approach. In SQL Server 2008, you could simply add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` or `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`, but in SQL Server 2005, try altering the stored procedure and adding the `WITH RECOMPILE` option. This will force SQL Server to consider a new plan every time, based on the incoming parameters.

Another option would be to build up the query dynamically based on whether `@bOnSale`, `@from` etc. are populated. In 2005 this will lead to plan cache bloat but you may be better off overall. This could completely avoid the Full-Text access, for example, when `@sku` is populated. Again, in SQL Server 2008 this is better, as you can stave off some of the plan cache bloat by using `Optimize for ad hoc workloads`.

Comment: It this part: `@bOnSale IS NULL OR @bOnSale=0`, repeated for several parameters

Comment: This is commonly called a 'catch all query'. In my oponion the best way to write these queries is with dynamic sql (using paremetrised calls to sp_ExecuteSql). Done properly its safe from sql infecton and will give a cusomised plan for each permutation of the query. Some referece: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2005.html

Comment: We had been trying to re-write this query to get away from dynamic SQL but I keep reading that it may be better.  I thought Dynamic SQL was  to be avoided whenever possible, but it seems in this case it's actually preferrable.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure of long standing can suddenly develop a case of the poor plan for all sorts of reasons. Just off the top of my head here are a few that stand out:

**Index Changes**

Dropping/Modifying indices on tables can cause queries that have had a perfectly fine execution plan for years to go south. Solution: don't do that. If you are going to do that, examine the dependencies on that table and make sure that everything is still getting a good execution plan.

**Table Statistics**

Index statistics can get fouled up for a number of reasons. For instance, large bulk loads of data into table(s) referenced by the stored procedure can bollux up index statistics on that table and thus mislead the query optimizer into constructing a poor execution plan. Solutions include 1 or more of the following:

- update statistics on the table(s) involved
- run `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` to flush the stored procedure cache.
- Execute `sp_recompile` on the offending stored procedure.

**Direct References To Stored Procedure Parameters**

Stored procedures whose queries directly use the parameters passed into the stored procedure get an execution plan based on the value of the parameters on the stored procedures first execution, when the plan is created and cached. If those parameter values are a little *outré*, the cached execution plan may perform well for the oddball cause but extremely poorly for the general case. The short-term Solution is torun `sp_recompile` or modify the stored procedure so that has the `with recompile` option (Note however, that this has a significant performance impact since the stored procedure gets recompiled for every execution. That means that compile locks are taken during the compilation process and that can (and does) cause blocking.

The correct fix for this problem is to declare a local variable within the stored procedure and set it to the value of the parameter. That turns the parameter value to an expression and breaks the plan's dependency on the parameter value. Floored me the first time I got hit with this problem.

Good luck!